# Derivative of a pullback and commutator

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm having difficulties trying to proof this derivative at t= 0:

$$\frac{d}{dt} \phi_t^{*} (gY) = [X, gY] $$

where $g$ is a function, $\phi^{*}_t$ is the pull-back by the small 
parameter $t$ and $X, Y$ are vectors. This kind of derivative is behind 
many results, like the Lie derivative, so I'm interested in learning it. 
My try:

$$\frac{d}{dt} \phi_t^{*} (gY) = 
\left(\frac{d}{dt}\phi^{*}_t\right)(gY)\rvert_{t=0} + 
\phi^{*}_t\frac{d}{dt}(gY)\rvert_{t=0} $$

but I don´t know how to proceed from there or even if this is correct. (This has been taken from Sternberg's "Curvature in Physics and Mathematics"). Thanks.

Comment: I assume $\phi_t$ is the flow of the vector field $X$?

Comment: Yes, it's the flow.

Comment: I think this is probably the same as what you're asking:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/303684/lie-derivative-of-a-vector-field?rq=1