# Show that the Lie derivative is equal to the commutator

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, riemannian-geometry

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d $  be open. 
Let $\epsilon > 0$. 
Let $(\phi_t)_{t \in (-\epsilon , \epsilon)} $ be a family in $\mathrm{Diff}(\Omega)$ such that $ \phi_0 = id_{\Omega}$ and $\phi_s \circ \phi_t = \phi_{s+t}$ for all s,t $ \in (-\epsilon , \epsilon)$ such that s+t $\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$  and such that $t \to \phi_t(x)$ is continuously differentiable for each fixed x $\in \Omega$. 
Let $X$ be the vector field defined by $X(f)(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{t=0}f(\phi _t(x))$.

We define the Lie derivative $L_XT$ of a tensor field $T$ of type $\binom{r}{s}$ on $\Omega$ w.r.t. $X$ by
$$(L_XT [\psi] ^{i_1...i_r}_{j_1...j_s}(y) = \frac {\partial}{\partial t}|_{t=0} T[ \psi \circ \phi _{-t}] ^{i_1...i_r}_{j_1...j_s}(y)  
$$
for $y \in \Omega$, $\psi \in \mathrm{Diff}(\Omega)$.

And finally, let g be a metric field on $\Omega$ and let $\nabla $ be the covariant derivative constructed from g.

Show for $\psi \in \mathrm{Diff}(\Omega))$

a) $(L_Xf )[\psi] = X[\psi]^j(\partial_jf)[\psi]$ for f a smooth function on $\Omega$

b) $(L_XY )[\psi]^j = (X^k \partial _k Y^j -Y^k\partial_kX^j)[\psi] = (X^k \nabla _k Y^j -Y^k \nabla_kX^j)[\psi]$

and therefore it is the commutator

and finally

c) $(L_Xg [\psi]_{jk} =  (X^l \partial _l g_{jk} - g_{jk} \partial _j X^l + g_{jl} \partial_kX^l)[\psi] = (\nabla_jX_k + \nabla _kX_j)[\psi] $

where as usual $X_k = g_{kl}X^l$.

---

Well. I just got that by definition the $\nabla _k $ is equal to $ \partial_k$

but for the other things I have no Idea..

thanks for help.

Comment: any hints for it ?

Comment: When you said that $\nabla_k=\partial_k$, you were kind of mistaken: actually, for an $(r,s)$ tensor along the basis vector $e_c$, $$ (\nabla_c T)^{a_1 \ldots a_r}{}_{b_1 \ldots b_s} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^c}T^{a_1 \ldots a_r}{}_{b_1 \ldots b_s}+\,\Gamma ^{a_1}{}_{dc} T ^{d \ldots a_r}{}_{b_1 \ldots b_s} + \cdots + \Gamma ^{a_r}{}_{dc} T ^{a_1 \ldots a_{r-1}d}{}_{b_1 \ldots b_s}$$ The $\Gamma^k_{\ i j}$ are the Christoffel symbols.

Comment: I've fixed some typos and factual errors in the main body of the question, and separated your update by the horizontal line.

Comment: No, $\nabla_k$ is the covariant derivative, not the partial derivative $\partial_k$, as @Sanath has correctly pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get all your definitions handy, and verify a number of things. 
Here is a to do list.

1) Make sure that you understand why $L_X T$ is a tensor field again.

2) Use **the chain rule** to show a) and observe that you can replace $\partial_k$ with $\nabla_k$ just because *on functions* these are the same thing.

3) The first equality in b) is actually shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/128214/2002).

4) To understand why the partial derivatives can be replaces by covariant derivatives (induced by the metric!) use the formula given by @Sanath in the comments. The main observation is that the Christoffel symbols are symmetric w.r.t. the bottom indices.

5) Put the things together and work out the rest.

Good luck!