# Why do two vector fields commute iff their flows do?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

I have the following definition, that is two vector fields $X$ and $Y$ commute if $[X,Y]=0$. There is result that states that two vector fields commute iff their flows do. This proposition is proved by using the following fact: given $F$ and $G$ the flows of $X$ and $Y$ respectively, we have that:

$$F_t \circ G_s (p)- G_s \circ F_t(p)=st[X,Y](p) + o (s^2 + t^2)$$

where $F_t$ and $G_s$ obviously mean the flow at times $t$ and $s$. This tells us that the bracket tells us "how much the two vector fields don't commute".

The question is: if the flows commute, it is obvious that $[X,Y]=0$. But for the other implication, why can I ignore the terms in $o(s^2 + t^2)$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128195/lie-derivative-of-a-vector-field-equals-the-lie-bracket seems to mostly answer your question, as it implies $\partial_t\phi_t^*Y=0$, where $\phi_t$ is the flow of $X$, so $\phi_t^*Y=Y$ for all $t$, which implies the commutation of the flows.

Comment: Seems right. That should be the Lie derivative in the particular case when you are deriving a vevctor field. I was wondering, though, what is inside that $o(s^2 +t^2)$?

Comment: I don't think this formula is going to do it to prove the reverse direction.

Comment: @TedShifrin  So you say that the right approach would be the one of the questin suggested above? Alos, only because I am curious, do you know what would be the terms contained on $o(s^2 +t^2)$?

Comment: I've never seen this formulation, but if you want to get a feel for it, write out the Taylor series for $e^{tX}e^{sY}-e^{sY}e^{tX}$ for square matrices $X$ and $Y$.