# How to show that for smooth vector fields, the pushforward is such that $\partial_t|_0{e^{-tX}}_*Y = -[X,Y]$?

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, exponential-function, vector-fields, lie-derivative

Consider two smooth vector fields $X,Y$, denote $[X,Y]$ their Lie bracket, $e^{tX}$ (resp. $e^{tY}$) the flow of $X$ (resp. $Y$) and $\varphi * X$ is the pushforward of $X$ by a diffeomorphism $\varphi$.

I would like to show:
$$
\frac{d }{dt}(e^{-tX}* Y) = e^{-tX} * [X,Y]
$$

using only definitions of the flow, pushforward and Lie brackets (no use of BCH...)

---

Observe that $[X,Y] = \frac{d}{dt}_{\mid t=0} e^{-tX}*Y$.

and

$$
e^{-tX}* Y = \frac{d }{ds}_{\mid s=0} e^{-tX}\circ e^{sY} \circ e^{tX}
$$

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/128195/173147

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would double check the question that's being asked since there seems to be a minus sign error.  You should actually have

$$
\left . \frac{d}{dt} \right |_{t=0} e^{-tX}*Y \;\; =\;\; -[X,Y].
$$

You get this by the following:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left . \frac{d}{dt} \right |_{t=0} e^{-tX}*Y & = & \left . \frac{d}{dt} \right |_{t=0} \left . \frac{d}{ds} \right |_{s=0} e^{-tX} e^{sY} e^{tX} \\
& = & \left . \frac{d}{dt} \right |_{t=0} \left (Ad_{e^{-tX}}\right )_*Y \\
& = & -XY + YX \;\; =\;\; -[X,Y].
\end{eqnarray*}

From this we can instead prove that 
$$
\frac{d}{dt} e^{-tX}*Y \;\; =\;\; e^{-tX}*\left (-[X,Y]\right ).
$$

Observe:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dt} e^{-tX}*Y  & = &  \frac{d}{dt}  \left . \frac{d}{ds} \right |_{s=0} e^{-tX}e^{sY}e^{tX} \\
& = & \frac{d}{dt}e^{-tX}Ye^{tX} \\
& = & \left (Ad_{e^{-tX}}\right )(-XY + YX) \\
& = & \left (Ad_{e^{-tX}}\right ) (-[X,Y]) \\
& = & \left . \frac{d}{ds} \right |_{s=0} e^{-tX} e^{-s[X,Y]}e^{tX} \\
& = & e^{-tX} * (-[X,Y]).
\end{eqnarray*}